"Do I press...? vs "Should I press...?

Do I press the pedal when driving?
Should I press the pedal when driving?

Whats the difference between the two?
Which one sounds more natural?

Both are OK, but the version with "should" is better. This is because technically, using "do" could imply the speaker is unsure of whether or not they actually press the pedal or not, instead of asking whether pressing the pedal is the correct thing to do. It would be helpful if you provide more context in your question around where the sentences came from (are they from an assignment? did you make them up yourself?) and what your perception of the difference between them is. This will help people give you better answers!

Practically speaking, the two questions, in context, are very similar and either would be idiomatic. Both are natural.
Do I press...? is asking about the pedal mechanism, how it functions, how one  operates it. Is that what is done while driving?
Should I press...? is asking whether it is appropriate or advisable to press the pedal. Of course, it would only be appropriate or advisable if that is how it actually functions.

Do I turn the nut holding the saw blade clockwise or counter-clockwise to loosen it?
Should I turn the nut holding the saw blade clockwise or counter-clockwise to loosen it?


"Do I.." can be asking about whether something happens. "Do you open the window while driving?" is not asking about the mechanism.

I didn't retype the full sentence but wrote "Do I...."  referring back to  "Do I press the pedal when driving?"  Also, I used the first person "Do I" not "Do you...?" There is a big difference in meaning of the question if the pronoun "you" does not mean "one" but refers to the person you're speaking to, and then, of course, it doesn't refer to how to operate something.
